# Add html content with if statement Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, dynamic, ngfor

I want to add an ion-icon into a ion-button when i disable the button.
I provide you some code below. `days` is an array with 30 json objects  :

```
 days = [ 
          { 
            dayId:1, 
            disabled:false
          },
          ....
        ];
```

Can i use the ngIf like that?
`

```
<ion-content padding>

  <div *ngFor="let day of days let i=index">
    <ion-button id={{day.day}} expand="block" size="large" (click)="test(day.day)" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days" disabled = {{day.disabled}} >DAY {{day.day}} 
        <div *ngIf="{{day.disabled}} == true;">
          <ion-icon slot="end" name="checkmark-circle"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </ion-button>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

`

Comment: IMO, yes you can use `*ngIf` this way,you can also use`<div *ngIf="day.disabled">`, are you getting any errors for the same?

Comment: `*ngIf="day.disabled"` is the correct syntax.

Comment: Yes guys it was that simple @Sarthak Aggarwal .Thanks alot you saved me some time.Post as an answer so i can verify it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, yes you can use `*ngIf` the way you are using it.

You can also use the following syntax for the same

```
<div *ngIf="day.disabled">

  // Your code

</div>
```